# What movie has a blonde lady in a red dress disappear from a pitch black room?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw just a few scenes from a movie in 2013. In one scene a lady in a red dress with blond hair disappears from a pitch black room. In another scene a man uses lockpicks while next to a woman to escape the room as it gets darker and closes in on them.

In the end credits someone says whoever is watching is definitely testing us.

I do not know the names of the actors.

What movie is this?

Answer (score 3):

[Fermat's Room?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Room)

That has a room where the walls are gradually closing in.

> Three mathematicians and one inventor are invited to a house under the premise of solving a great enigma, and told to use pseudonyms based on famous historical mathematicians. At the house, they are trapped in a room. They must solve puzzles given by the host, who calls himself "Fermat", in order to escape the slowly closing walls of the room.